# How to `unlet` a variable using from a `argdo` statement in VIM

Tags: buffers, variables

I do have a bunch of XHTML files and I need to put an `@id` for all the `p` elements inside all those files.

I have tried the following `argdo` approach in the following way:

```
:cd d:\testfiles\
:args *.xhtml
:argdo let i = 1 | g/<p/s/<p/\=printf("<p id=\"para%02d\"", i)/ | let i = i + 1
```

Now, this works fine. Doing it by this way value of `i` is getting incremented all the time. But, I want it to use `unlet i`, whenever `argdo` executes to a new buffer. In short, variable `i` must be set to `1` for each item in the `arg-list`.

I also have tried to use `|unlet i` at the end of the `argdo statements` or at the beginning of the `argdo statements`. But both ways have failed.

---

Is there any workaround? I am very new to `vim`. Using it only a few months and loving it day by day. Pointing out my error to get job done, is greatly appreciated.

Comment: @muru: thanks a ton! This is so easy...and I was heard of that...but never used it before...

Comment: *both the ways are failed* is incorrect grammatically - it should be either  *both ways have failed*, or just *both ways failed*.

Comment: @muru: perhaps....you're right...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you use a variable without a scope (`i` instead of `b:i` or `w:i`, etc.) outside of a function, you're using a global variable. From [`:h internal-variables`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/eval.txt.html#internal-variables):

```
There are several name spaces for variables.  Which one is to be used is
specified by what is prepended:

                (nothing) In a function: local to a function; otherwise: global
buffer-variable    b:   Local to the current buffer.
window-variable    w:   Local to the current window.
tabpage-variable   t:   Local to the current tab page.
global-variable    g:   Global.
local-variable     l:   Local to a function.
script-variable    s:   Local to a :source'ed Vim script.
function-argument  a:   Function argument (only inside a function).
vim-variable       v:   Global, predefined by Vim.
```

A plain `i` is a variable common to all buffers. Since you need to reset the variable for each file, and each file will be in a separate buffer, you can use buffer-local variables (`b:i` instead of `i`).

Comment: Thanks for the explanation...now i understand where i was doing wrong...as i am already mentioned a very new to `vim` but very fond of it... i was regular user of "epsilon" (a emacs style editor), but i never have use before such a great editor like VIM...thanks again for your kind assistance...